# Package calc error`\let ' invalid at this point, probably wrong unit of measure

Tags: titlesec, titletoc, calc, unit-of-measure

I'll attach a MWE which replicates the problem

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside,notitlepage,reqno]{book}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}


\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber,hyperref]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliografia.bib}
\usepackage[sf,sc]{titlesec}
\usepackage[dvipsnames, usenames]{color}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor = RoyalBlue,citecolor = OliveGreen,linktocpage]{hyperref}


\linespread{1.1}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\titleformat{\chapter}
{\vspace*{-50pt}\Huge\scshape}
{\thechapter.}
{}
{}
[\vspace*{-15pt}]

\titlecontents{chapter}
[0em]
{\vspace*{0.5em}\scshape\sffamily}
{\contentslabel[\hfill\upshape\bfseries\thecontentslabel\phantom{..}]{3em}\enspace}
{\hspace{-\labelwidth\phantom{1..}}}
{\hspace{3em}\llap{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-1.3pc][r]{\upshape\thecontentspage}}}
[\addvspace{0.2em}]

  

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\tableofcontents

\titleformat{\chapter}
{\vspace*{-70pt}\center\Huge\scshape}
{\thechapter.}
{10pt}
{}
\chapter{hey whts'up}
\section{1111}
\cite{nicoloso:manuscript}
\chapter{hellooo}
\cite{heuberger:planarity}
\section{222222}
\appendix
\chapter{this is the appendix part}
there is some random text and then the code part.
\section{a random section}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\vspace*{-50pt}\Huge\scshape}{\thechapter.}{10pt}{}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

here's the `bibliografia.bib` file I used for the bibliography:

```
@article{heuberger:planarity,
     author       = {Heuberger, C.},
     title        = {On planarity and colorability of circulant graphs},
     journaltitle = {Discrete Mathematics},
     date         = {2003},
     pages        = {26:153-169},
}


@unpublished{nicoloso:manuscript,
     author       = {Nicoloso, S. and Pietropaoli, U.},
     title        = {Vertex-colouring of some 3-chromatic circulant graphs with gcd(n, a) mod 3 = 0},
     date         = {2020},
}
```

Thanks in advance for anyone who'd like to help me, it would be awesome if one can enlighten me about these `calc`errors...

## EDIT 2

This is the .log of what happens when I try to ignore the errors, it's not complete because it's too long and it doesn't fit in the question body:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.2.8)  8 FEB 2021 16:39
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**tesi
(./tesi.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-06>
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk11.clo
File: bk11.clo 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count177
\c@chapter=\count178
\c@section=\count179
\c@subsection=\count180
\c@subsubsection=\count181
\c@paragraph=\count182
\c@subparagraph=\count183
\c@figure=\count184
\c@table=\count185
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/minted/minted.sty
Package: minted 2017/07/19 v2.5 Yet another Pygments shim for LaTeX

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks15
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2020-10-07 v3.14 Key value format for package options (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fvextra/fvextra.sty
Package: fvextra 2019/02/04 v1.4 fvextra - extensions and patches for fancyvrb

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count186
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty
Package: fancyvrb 2021/01/20 v3.7 verbatim text (tvz,hv)
\FV@CodeLineNo=\count187
\FV@InFile=\read2
\FV@TabBox=\box47
\c@FancyVerbLine=\count188
\FV@StepNumber=\count189
\FV@OutFile=\write3
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/upquote/upquote.sty
Package: upquote 2012/04/19 v1.3 upright-quote and grave-accent glyphs in verba
tim
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lineno/lineno.sty
Package: lineno 2005/11/02 line numbers on paragraphs v4.41
\linenopenalty=\count190
\output=\toks16
\linenoprevgraf=\count191
\linenumbersep=\dimen139
\linenumberwidth=\dimen140
\c@linenumber=\count192
\c@pagewiselinenumber=\count193
\c@LN@truepage=\count194
\c@internallinenumber=\count195
\c@internallinenumbers=\count196
\quotelinenumbersep=\dimen141
\bframerule=\dimen142
\bframesep=\dimen143
\bframebox=\box48
LaTeX Info: Redefining \\ on input line 3056.
)
\c@FV@TrueTabGroupLevel=\count197
\c@FV@TrueTabCounter=\count198
\FV@TabBox@Group=\box49
\FV@TmpLength=\skip49
\c@FV@HighlightLinesStart=\count199
\c@FV@HighlightLinesStop=\count266
\FV@LoopCount=\count267
\FV@NCharsBox=\box50
\FV@BreakIndent=\dimen144
\FV@BreakIndentNChars=\count268
\FV@BreakSymbolSepLeft=\dimen145
\FV@BreakSymbolSepLeftNChars=\count269
\FV@BreakSymbolSepRight=\dimen146
\FV@BreakSymbolSepRightNChars=\count270
\FV@BreakSymbolIndentLeft=\dimen147
\FV@BreakSymbolIndentLeftNChars=\count271
\FV@BreakSymbolIndentRight=\dimen148
\FV@BreakSymbolIndentRightNChars=\count272
\c@FancyVerbLineBreakLast=\count273
\FV@LineBox=\box51
\FV@LineIndentBox=\box52
\FV@LineWidth=\dimen149
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty
Package: calc 2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count274
\calc@Bcount=\count275
\calc@Adimen=\dimen150
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen151
\calc@Askip=\skip50
\calc@Bskip=\skip51
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count276
\calc@Cskip=\skip52
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/shellesc.sty
Package: shellesc 2019/11/08 v1.0c unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
Package shellesc Info: Unrestricted shell escape enabled on input line 75.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifplatform/ifplatform.sty
Package: ifplatform 2017/10/13 v0.4a Testing for the operating system

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/catchfile/catchfile.sty
Package: catchfile 2019/12/09 v1.8 Catch the contents of a file (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
runsystem(uname -s > "tesi.w18")...executed.

 (./tesi.w18)
runsystem(rm -- "tesi.w18")...executed.

) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex
\integerpart=\count277
\decimalpart=\count278
)
Package: xstring 2019/02/06 v1.83 String manipulations (CT)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/framed/framed.sty
Package: framed 2011/10/22 v 0.96: framed or shaded text with page breaks
\OuterFrameSep=\skip53
\fb@frw=\dimen152
\fb@frh=\dimen153
\FrameRule=\dimen154
\FrameSep=\dimen155
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty
Package: float 2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
\c@float@type=\count279
\float@exts=\toks17
\float@box=\box53
\@float@everytoks=\toks18
\@floatcapt=\box54
)
\minted@appexistsfile=\read3
\minted@bgbox=\box55
\minted@code=\write4
\c@minted@FancyVerbLineTemp=\count280
\c@minted@pygmentizecounter=\count281
\@float@every@listing=\toks19
\c@listing=\count282
)
runsystem(mkdir -p _minted-tesi)...executed.


(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2020/08/10 v2.0s Standard LaTeX package
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2020/08/01 v1.3d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks20
\inpenc@posthook=\toks21
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2021/01/26 3.53 The Babel package

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
File: babel.def 2021/01/26 3.53 Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count283
\U@D=\dimen156
\l@babelnohyphens=\language86

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def)
\bbl@readstream=\read4
)
\bbl@dirlevel=\count284

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf
Language: english 2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system
Package babel Info: \l@canadian = using hyphenrules for english
(babel)             (\language0) on input line 102.
Package babel Info: \l@australian = using hyphenrules for ukenglish
(babel)             (\language21) on input line 105.
Package babel Info: \l@newzealand = using hyphenrules for ukenglish
(babel)             (\language21) on input line 108.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-italian/italian.ldf
Language: italian 2020/05/21 v.1.4.04 Italian support for the babel system
\it@lettering=\count285
\it@doublequoteactive=\count286
\it@ISOcompliance=\count287
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
Package: biblatex 2020/12/31 v3.16 programmable bibliographies (PK/MW)

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
Package: logreq 2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
\lrq@indent=\count288

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def
File: logreq.def 2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip16
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
\c@tabx@nest=\count289
\c@listtotal=\count290
\c@listcount=\count291
\c@liststart=\count292
\c@liststop=\count293
\c@citecount=\count294
\c@citetotal=\count295
\c@multicitecount=\count296
\c@multicitetotal=\count297
\c@instcount=\count298
\c@maxnames=\count299
\c@minnames=\count300
\c@maxitems=\count301
\c@minitems=\count302
\c@citecounter=\count303
\c@maxcitecounter=\count304
\c@savedcitecounter=\count305
\c@uniquelist=\count306
\c@uniquename=\count307
\c@refsection=\count308
\c@refsegment=\count309
\c@maxextratitle=\count310
\c@maxextratitleyear=\count311
\c@maxextraname=\count312
\c@maxextradate=\count313
\c@maxextraalpha=\count314
\c@abbrvpenalty=\count315
\c@highnamepenalty=\count316
\c@lownamepenalty=\count317
\c@maxparens=\count318
\c@parenlevel=\count319
\blx@tempcnta=\count320
\blx@tempcntb=\count321
\blx@tempcntc=\count322
\blx@maxsection=\count323
\blx@maxsegment@0=\count324
\blx@notetype=\count325
\blx@parenlevel@text=\count326
\blx@parenlevel@foot=\count327
\blx@sectionciteorder@0=\count328
\blx@entrysetcounter=\count329
\blx@biblioinstance=\count330
\labelnumberwidth=\skip54
\labelalphawidth=\skip55
\biblabelsep=\skip56
\bibitemsep=\skip57
\bibnamesep=\skip58
\bibinitsep=\skip59
\bibparsep=\skip60
\bibhang=\skip61
\blx@bcfin=\read5
\blx@bcfout=\write5
\blx@langwohyphens=\language87
\c@mincomprange=\count331
\c@maxcomprange=\count332
\c@mincompwidth=\count333
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex default data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-dm.def' found.

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def
File: blx-dm.def 2020/12/31 v3.16 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex style data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'numeric.dbx' not found.
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex custom data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex-dm.cfg' not found.
\c@afterword=\count334
\c@savedafterword=\count335
\c@annotator=\count336
\c@savedannotator=\count337
\c@author=\count338
\c@savedauthor=\count339
\c@bookauthor=\count340
\c@savedbookauthor=\count341
\c@commentator=\count342
\c@savedcommentator=\count343
\c@editor=\count344
\c@savededitor=\count345
\c@editora=\count346
\c@savededitora=\count347
\c@editorb=\count348
\c@savededitorb=\count349
\c@editorc=\count350
\c@savededitorc=\count351
\c@foreword=\count352
\c@savedforeword=\count353
\c@holder=\count354
\c@savedholder=\count355
\c@introduction=\count356
\c@savedintroduction=\count357
\c@namea=\count358
\c@savednamea=\count359
\c@nameb=\count360
\c@savednameb=\count361
\c@namec=\count362
\c@savednamec=\count363
\c@translator=\count364
\c@savedtranslator=\count365
\c@shortauthor=\count366
\c@savedshortauthor=\count367
\c@shorteditor=\count368
\c@savedshorteditor=\count369
\c@labelname=\count370
\c@savedlabelname=\count371
\c@institution=\count372
\c@savedinstitution=\count373
\c@lista=\count374
\c@savedlista=\count375
\c@listb=\count376
\c@savedlistb=\count377
\c@listc=\count378
\c@savedlistc=\count379
\c@listd=\count380
\c@savedlistd=\count381
\c@liste=\count382
\c@savedliste=\count383
\c@listf=\count384
\c@savedlistf=\count385
\c@location=\count386
\c@savedlocation=\count387
\c@organization=\count388
\c@savedorganization=\count389
\c@origlocation=\count390
\c@savedoriglocation=\count391
\c@origpublisher=\count392
\c@savedorigpublisher=\count393
\c@publisher=\count394
\c@savedpublisher=\count395
\c@language=\count396
\c@savedlanguage=\count397
\c@origlanguage=\count398
\c@savedoriglanguage=\count399
\c@pageref=\count400
\c@savedpageref=\count401
\shorthandwidth=\skip62
\shortjournalwidth=\skip63
\shortserieswidth=\skip64
\shorttitlewidth=\skip65
\shortauthorwidth=\skip66
\shorteditorwidth=\skip67
\locallabelnumberwidth=\skip68
\locallabelalphawidth=\skip69
\localshorthandwidth=\skip70
\localshortjournalwidth=\skip71
\localshortserieswidth=\skip72
\localshorttitlewidth=\skip73
\localshortauthorwidth=\skip74
\localshorteditorwidth=\skip75
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load compatibility code...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-compat.def' found.

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def
File: blx-compat.def 2020/12/31 v3.16 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load generic definitions...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.def' found.

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def
File: biblatex.def 2020/12/31 v3.16 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
\c@textcitecount=\count402
\c@textcitetotal=\count403
\c@textcitemaxnames=\count404
\c@biburlbigbreakpenalty=\count405
\c@biburlbreakpenalty=\count406
\c@biburlnumpenalty=\count407
\c@biburlucpenalty=\count408
\c@biburllcpenalty=\count409
\biburlbigskip=\muskip17
\biburlnumskip=\muskip18
\biburlucskip=\muskip19
\biburllcskip=\muskip20
\c@smartand=\count410
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'numeric'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'numeric.bbx' found.

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/numeric.bbx
File: numeric.bbx 2020/12/31 v3.16 biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'standard'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'standard.bbx' found.

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx
File: standard.bbx 2020/12/31 v3.16 biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)
\c@bbx:relatedcount=\count411
\c@bbx:relatedtotal=\count412
))
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load citation style 'numeric'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'numeric.cbx' found.

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/numeric.cbx
File: numeric.cbx 2020/12/31 v3.16 biblatex citation style (PK/MW)
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcitetext'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\smartcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\supercite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\smartcites'.
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load configuration file...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.cfg' found.

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg
File: biblatex.cfg 
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titlesec.sty
Package: titlesec 2019/10/16 v2.13 Sectioning titles
\ttl@box=\box56
\beforetitleunit=\skip76
\aftertitleunit=\skip77
\ttl@plus=\dimen157
\ttl@minus=\dimen158
\ttl@toksa=\toks22
\titlewidth=\dimen159
\titlewidthlast=\dimen160
\titlewidthfirst=\dimen161
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstmisc.sty
File: lstmisc.sty 2020/03/24 1.8d (Carsten Heinz)
\c@lstnumber=\count419
\lst@skipnumbers=\count420
\lst@framebox=\box58
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.cfg
File: listings.cfg 2020/03/24 1.8d listings configuration
))
Package: listings 2020/03/24 1.8d (Carsten Heinz)

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/appendix/appendix.sty
Package: appendix 2020/02/08 v1.2c extra appendix facilities
\c@@pps=\count421
\c@@ppsavesec=\count422
\c@@ppsaveapp=\count423
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titletoc.sty
Package: titletoc 2019/10/16 v2.13 TOC entries
\ttl@leftsep=\dimen166
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2021-02-07 v7.00h Hypertext links for LaTeX

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty
Package: pdfescape 2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty
Package: hycolor 2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty
Package: letltxmacro 2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen167
\Hy@linkcounter=\count424
\Hy@pagecounter=\count425

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2021-02-07 v7.00h Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PD1 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PD1
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref-langpatches.def
File: hyperref-langpatches.def 2021-02-07 v7.00h Hyperref: patches for babel la
nguages
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty
Package: intcalc 2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count426

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def
File: puenc.def 2021-02-07 v7.00h Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PU ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PU
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `colorlinks' set `true' on input line 4059.
Package hyperref Info: Option `linktocpage' set `true' on input line 4059.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4178.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4183.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4186.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4193.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4198.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4431.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count427
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 4790.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen168

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
Package: bitset 2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty
Package: bigintcalc 2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
))
\Fld@menulength=\count428
\Field@Width=\dimen169
\Fld@charsize=\dimen170
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6061.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6066.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6069.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6076.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring ON on input line 6079.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6086.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6091.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6131.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6135.

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty
Package: atbegshi-ltx 2020/08/17 v1.0a Emulation of the original atbegshi packa
ge
with kernel methods
)
\Hy@abspage=\count429
\c@Item=\count430
\c@Hfootnote=\count431
)
Package hyperref Info: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
File: hpdftex.def 2021-02-07 v7.00h Hyperref driver for pdfTeX

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty
Package: atveryend-ltx 2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atvery packag
e
with kernel methods
)
\Fld@listcount=\count432
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count433

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2019/12/05 v1.9 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty
Package: uniquecounter 2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
86.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip78
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
Package: textcomp 2020/02/02 v2.0n Standard LaTeX package
)
runsystem(which pygmentize && touch tesi.aex)...executed.

runsystem(rm tesi.aex)...executed.


\@quotelevel=\count434
\@quotereset=\count435
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2021-02-06 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count436
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box59
)

(./tesi.aux)
\openout1 = `tesi.aux'.

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx
File: english.lbx 2020/12/31 v3.16 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
)

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2021-02-06 L3 programming layer (loader) 
)
Package biblatex Info: ... and expl3
(biblatex)             2021-02-06 L3 programming layer (loader) 
(biblatex)             is new enough (at least 2020/04/06),
(biblatex)             setting 'casechanger=expl3'.

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-case-expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse-2020-10-
01.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse-generic.
tex)))
Package: blx-case-expl3 2020/12/31 v3.16 expl3 case changing code for biblatex
)
\openout5 = `tesi.bcf'.

Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliographic data...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'tesi.bbl' found.
 (./tesi.bbl)
Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 23.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 23.

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count437
\scratchdimen=\dimen171
\scratchbox=\box60
\nofMPsegments=\count438
\nofMParguments=\count439
\everyMPshowfont=\toks24
\MPscratchCnt=\count440
\MPscratchDim=\dimen172
\MPnumerator=\count441
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count442
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks25
)
\c@lstlisting=\count443
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring ON on input line 23.
 (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2021-04-02 v2.47 Cross-referencing by name of section

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty
Package: refcount 2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.s
ty
Package: gettitlestring 2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count444
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 23.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 23.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 23.
 (./tesi.out) (./tesi.out)
\@outlinefile=\write6
\openout6 = `tesi.out'.

 (./tesi.toc

! Package calc Error: `\let ' invalid at this point.

See the calc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.21 ...ne {chapter}{Bibliografia}{5}{appendix*.2}
                                                  %
? 
! Extra \else.
\contentsline ...e }{#3}\hyper@linkend }\fi \else 
                                                  \def \Hy@temp {#3}\ifx \Hy...
l.21 ...ne {chapter}{Bibliografia}{5}{appendix*.2}
                                                  %
? 

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.21 ...ne {chapter}{Bibliografia}{5}{appendix*.2}
                                                  %
? 

! Package calc Error: `\let ' invalid at this point.

See the calc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.21 ...ne {chapter}{Bibliografia}{5}{appendix*.2}
                                                  %
? 
)
\tf@toc=\write7
\openout7 = `tesi.toc'.

 [1


{/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
Capitolo 1.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/cmss/m/sc' in size <24.88> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/cmr/m/sc' tried instead on input line 52.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/cmss/m/sc' in size <14.4> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/cmr/m/sc' tried instead on input line 53.

[2

]
Capitolo 2.
[3

]
Appendice A.
[4

] [5

] (./tesi.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `tesi.out' has not changed.
(rerunfilecheck)             Checksum: B56E9FBC0589F6D36036F09F3141BAD1;776.

Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                tesi
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

Package logreq Info: Writing requests to 'tesi.run.xml'.
\openout1 = `tesi.run.xml'.

 )
(\end occurred inside a group at level 10)

### semi simple group (level 10) entered at line 21 (\begingroup)
### semi simple group (level 9) entered at line 21 (\begingroup)
### simple group (level 8) entered at line 21 ({)
### semi simple group (level 7) entered at line 21 (\begingroup)
### semi simple group (level 6) entered at line 21 (\begingroup)
### semi simple group (level 5) entered at line 21 (\begingroup)
### semi simple group (level 4) entered at line 21 (\begingroup)
### simple group (level 3) entered at line 21 ({)
### semi simple group (level 2) entered at line 21 (\begingroup)
### semi simple group (level 1) entered at line 45 (\begingroup)
### bottom level
(\end occurred when \ifnum on line 21 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 21 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifcase on line 21 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 21 was incomplete)
```

Probably the problem is in that line you pointed out, my goal was to make aligned titles in the table of contents and with those settings I was able to get the result you can see in the photo. I guess it's not the correct way to get it and it's clashing with the `calc`package[image: toc sample]

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) as always on this site, you are much more likely to get any help if you provide a full minimal example instead of a sniplet like this. A full minimal example allows others to test your code as is. Here we have add stuff before we can even test your code.

Comment: Plus none of your provided code even mentions, `minted`, `calc` or `biblatex`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm posting a MWE soon, I hope it'll be okay

Comment: Can you provide some information about which latex instalation you are using, perhaps also package versions (if you add `\listfiles` before `\documentclass` a list is written to the log.

Comment: I get no errors and after running `biber` by hand (not sure why it did not run automatically on my system) it seems to run just fine

Comment: I've tried updating all packages (I've already done that some days ago), but I still get the error, exactly the 2nd time I run `pdflatex` after running `biber`. I've posted an edit with the informations you asked me. Thanks a lot

Comment: Please don't add a snip of the log, post the entire log of your compilation of this particular example. We can tell a lot from the data before the error.

Comment: BTW have you tried deleting aux files (including `.toc`, `.out` etc)?

Comment: Also there is a lot of stuff here that does not make any sense, `\hspace{-\labelwidth\phantom{1..}}`: `\phantom{1..}` is not a length, I'm quite surprised that this actually compiles. Perhaps your should start over and explain what exaxctly the goal is here.

Comment: Thanks again daleif. I guess the problem it's in that line you pointed out. Anyway I tried posting the whole .log but it does not fit the question body, and I explained what was my original goal by writing those settings for the titlecontents command. You can see in the photo the result I got before the use of `minted` and the problem from the `calc` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I've found a solution: deleting the `\phantom{1..}` and typing a proportional length instead would fix that error. Moreover, there was another error with the `\dimexpr` command which I fixed just by deleting the command.